# 2000 Volkswagen jetta won't move

Tags: vw, clutch, manual-transmission, jetta

in my 2000 Volkswagen Jetta 5-speed manual there's a burning smell coming from the motor I can shift into any Gear with or without using the clutch but yet it wont turn off or stall and it won't move at all can anyone please help me

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 2):

I believe the friction disk material in your clutch has completely gone. This means there's no way for power to get from your engine to your transmission. Sorry for such a short answer, but this is the only thing I can see which it might be from your description.

Comment: second this time for a clutch,have someone teach you before you burn up the next one to